# Develop client library for MQTT in C

Tags: microcontroller, mqtt

I want to develop a c client library for MQTT, to make my PIC 8 bit micro-controller to talk to an MQTT broker( say Active MQ). I am relatively new to this field. Can anyone suggest where can i start . I need to implement just  CONNECT, SUBSCRIBE,UNSUBSCRIBE, PUBLISH nad DISCONNECT API's to start with.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some useful info on the protocol itself: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/MQTT_V3.1_Protocol_Specific.pdf - also give a try to http://mosquitto.org/

Answer (score 2):

You need to get ethernet working first, then just implement the protocol... :)

A good place to look would be the arduino client (http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/) that should have solved a lot of what you need to do.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure a AMQP client would be able to run on a limited system like the AVR (but a great system tough).

You will need at least the following: 
 - The TCP/IP stack;
 - Enough memory to hold some frames (4096 bytes or maybe smaller but not often);

If you think the arduino will handle all this, I would start from the rabbitmq-c library and strip it down.

Other option, and if the rabbitmq-c isn't small enough, and your goals are just to publish messages, take a look at STOMP and how to combine it with RabbitMQ or other AMQP. Stomp has a very small footprint and will, probably, be the best shot to give.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSockets.NET since you can connect any device with TCP/IP to XSockets and then talk to other devices.

It will basically work like this.

1. Setup a XSockets server somewhere (localhost to start with)
2. Connect from the Arduino to XSockets
3. Use XSockets publish/subscribe pattern do send/receive data between arduino and any other device connected to XSockets

Simple vide demo here: [Arduino pub/sub with XSockets](http://youtu.be/FbviMZ9dFE8?t=3m4s)

If you want to mix in any other tech do it from XSockets since that wil be easier than writing stuff on the Arduino.

EDIT: Just saw that you did not say Arduino... 8-bit PIC micro-controller might be another story :) I have just connected Arduino and Netduino